# Setting up Motorola xoom simulator to test web applications

Tags: motorola, xoom

I have a web application which is developed for Ipad and which works fine in Ipad. I want to test it in motorola xoom. Can any one point me or guide me on how to set up motorola xoom simulator which has browser so that I could test my Web App in it?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the pointing me to the right place. I would like to know if there is a way where we can debug web app in galaxy tab directly.. not through emulator but debugging directly the device..something like weinre for IPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you need is on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html).

Here's a quick rundown:
 - Install the Android SDK
 - Create an AVD (Android Virtual Device) with the specs you're looking for (ie. resolution)
 - Run the emulator with the AVD (emulator -avd )

Comment: Thanks for the pointing me to the right place. I would like to know if there is a way where we can debug web app in galaxy tab directly.. not through emulator but debugging directly the device..something like weinre for IPad

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that. Sounds like a good topic for a new question.